# How to pass coordinates of google geolocation to another function?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

My problem is that when I print the lat and long of my position to the console it works but when I pass them to my calculate function the console says they are undefined.

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } 
    else {
        location.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {

    console.log(position.coords.longitude); 

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

}

function calculate(lat,lng){
    var homeCoord = new Array();
    var awayCoord = new Array();
    console.log(lng);
    console.log(lat);

    homeCoord[0] = lat;
    homeCoord[1] = lng;
    awayCoord = myGeocodeFirst();

    var combinedLat = homeCoord[0]+awayCoord[0];
    var combinedLong = awayCoord[1]+homeCoord[1];

    console.log(combinedLat+" "+combinedLong);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Forgot to put error output:
undefined calculate.js:59

undefined calculate.js:60

NaN NaN calculate.js:69
[40.1208752, 9.012892599999986] calculate.js:44

Comment: where is your calculate() call?

Comment: calculate() is called by a button in my html.

Comment: The problem is most likely how you're passing values to that function. Can you show how you're calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in the callback function:

```
function showPosition(position) {

    console.log(position.coords.longitude); 

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    calculate(lat,lng);

}

function calculate(lat,lng){
    var homeCoord = new Array();
    var awayCoord = new Array();
    console.log(lng);
    console.log(lat);

    homeCoord[0] = lat;
    homeCoord[1] = lng;
    awayCoord = myGeocodeFirst();

    var combinedLat = homeCoord[0]+awayCoord[0];
    var combinedLong = awayCoord[1]+homeCoord[1];

    console.log(combinedLat+" "+combinedLong);
}
```

Comment: This works but not the way I wanted it to. I will just have to restructure my code. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this might be interesting: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)